# Is this the proper way to assign a view method to multiple URLS?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-userena

I guess I should first of all ask if this is possible, and second am I doing this correctly?  I am just trying to make userena_views.signup to a second url (test) and also assign a different template on the second one.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Signup, signin and signout
    url(r'^signup/$',
       userena_views.signup,
       name='userena_signup'),
    url(r'^test/$',
      userena_views.signup, {'template_name': 'myproject/templates/custom.html',},
      name='userena_signup')
```

Comment: You can, provided you give unique names. Rather.. i should ask, did you try this code ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response (I see you respond to many of my previous questions).  I did not try this code because this is located inside Site-Packages/Userena, and I'm a little paranoid to change things inside this directory.

Comment: Nooooo - You should __never__ be touching code in sites directory. You can have this url pattern in your root url conf for now, and call the userna package. Just make sure `name` attribute is unique

Comment: With Userena, all of the templates are located in site-packages. I want to customize these templates so I am forced to go into site-packages. The only other option I can think of is to create new templates inside my project directory, but the problem then, is that I think I still have to go into site-packages and edit views and replace templates with the new ones I created.

Comment: Django is smart to pick your templates first. Just follow the directory structure and put the modified templates in the templates directory of the project

Answer (score 0):

How I would go about that is to pass in a parameter. Inside the view you would assign the template based on which parameter was passed in. It is a little messy and better not to modify the site-package code, but sometimes it is necessary.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Signup, signin and signout
    url(r'^(?P<signup_type>signup)/$', userena_views.signup, name='userena_signup'),
    url(r'^(?P<signup_type>test)/$', userena_views.signup, name='test_userena_signup')
```